# Error not implemented - error in file temp_.rpt operation not implemented VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've got the error

> Error not implemented - error in file temp_.rpt operation not implemented

Please help on solving this error. I did check the font and having W r access to temp file ?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1431748.aspx?Crystal+Report+Export+To+PDF+Error+Operation+not+yet+implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just install the accessdatabaseengin.exe 32.bit

from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

it solve the problem because i was design the access data base on ms access 2013
and on my pc i have ms access 2007